# Java AffineTransform to rotate a GeneralPath

Tags: java, graphics, affinetransform

I can understand this behavior of AffineTransform.
This is my code:

```
// draw the needle
float needleX, needleY;
needleX = am.x_arc_center;
needleY = am.y_final_arc;
GeneralPath needle = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_NON_ZERO);
needle.moveTo(needleX, needleY);
needle.lineTo(needleX - 3, needleY - 3);
needle.lineTo(needleX - am.radius, needleY);
needle.lineTo(needleX - 3, needleY + 3);
needle.closePath();
g2d.fill(needle);
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.rotate(Math.PI / 6);
needle.transform(at);
g2d.draw(needle);
```

I prepare a needle with a GeneralPath and after I want to rotate it to indicate a precise angle between 0 and PI / 2.
But it draws only a horizontal needle and transform seems to be ignored.
What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: draw the path with g2d.fill(needle); without the transform - then draw with the transform (just the g2d.draw(needle); at the end no  g2d.fill(needle); in between) in a diferent panel/image etc - are they the same?

Comment: yes they are the same :-(

Comment: I'm very sad... This simple code draw nothing...

    // Save current transform context
    AffineTransform current = g2d.getTransform();
    g2d.setPaint(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 10);
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.rotate(Math.PI / 6);
    g2d.transform(at);
    g2d.fill(r);
    g2d.draw(r);
    // restore original transform context
    g2d.setTransform(current);

if I remove the g2d.transform, the rectangle appear...
Why?